# How do you auto-push commits to remote repository in TortoiseGit?

Tags: windows, git, push, git-push, tortoisegit

I have set up a remote repository with the URL, the credentials (accounts) set up for that repository, and I have my local branch ready to push new commits to the repository.

Now, I would like to auto-push my commits to the remote repository in TortoiseGIT, after committing my changes.

Below shows how to set up the configurations in TortoiseGIT for auto-pushing commits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the default installation and configurations for TortoiseGIT v2.3.0.0 and Git for Windows 2.11.0.windows.1:

1. Prepare your commit.
2. Do `Right click > Commit...` and it should open up the Commit dialog.
3. Once your commit messages are typed in, at the bottom, select the dropdown menu on the `Commit` button, and choose `Commit & Push`.
4. It should then open up the Push dialog.
5. In the Push dialog, in the `Ref` section, choose the remote branch via the dropdown menu, or type in the remote branch name. It must not be empty.
6. Change the `Destination` section if necessary.
7. In the `Options` section, enable the bottom-most option: `Always push to the selected remote branch for this local branch.`
8. Press OK.

Your commit will then be pushed to the repository. Subsequent commits will automatically be pushed to the repository once you commit your changes.

Comment: Hmm, my right click only has _Git-commit -> "master" ..._
And the following dialog does not have a _Commit_ button, only OK.
[Right click menu] (https://www.wis.no/filer/tortoisegit-commit.png)
[Commit dialog] (https://www.wis.no/filer/tortoisegit-commit-dialog.png)
We are using TortoiseGit version: 1.8.4.0 og git version 2.11.0.windows.1.
I have kind of solved it with hooks, but it's not ideal, since I have to quit the push dialog that appears after the commit.
So is this some kind of preferences or settings?

Comment: Well, I used the default settings after a full reinstallation of the latest TortoiseGIT and the newest Git for Windows. I thought my wiki would help others out, but it doesn't handle cases where you have a different setup.

Comment: Could you check what version you have? I can't remember have changed anything in the settings, but last install was an upgrade, so maybe I "inherited" something. I'll look around in the settings...

Comment: @OveHalseth TortoiseGIT v2.3.0.0, git version 2.11.0.windows.1

Comment: I have updated my post mentioning that I'm really using the latest stable versions of TortoiseGIT. I don't think prior versions (less than v2.1.0.0, I think. Not sure...) have this new option to auto-push commits.